# How to set a cookie on a redirect in python

Tags: python, redirect, cookies

I am writing a Proxy Server where I will intercept a request, and check the header to see if it has a cookie named URID, and if it does not, I want to redirect the request to a fw.asta.com, see if this domain has a cookie called URID, and if it doesn't, I want to set the cookie for fw.cisco.com, and then redirect to the originally intended site, and then set the same cookie for that site as well.  If the cookie exists for the fw.asta.com site, I will use that cookie to redirect to the originally intended site, and if the originally intended site has the URID cookie, I will simply serve the request on behalf of the site.

So I have been struggling with this for quite some time.  I have a feeling like I don't understand what actually happens when I set a cookie during a redirection.

I have this code right here:

```
def do_GET(self):
    #seperate the path into parts
    (scm, netloc, path, params, query, fragment) = urlparse.urlparse(self.path, 'http')

    #check the header for the urid cookie, returns the URID if present
    urid = self.find_urid()


    if netloc == 'fw.asta.com':
        if urid:
            #redirect to the originally intended site and set the cookie
            path = self.path[23:]
            self.redirect_with_urid(path, urid)
        else:
            #redirect to fw.asta.com
            urid = 333
            self.redirect_with_urid(self.path, urid)
    else:
        if urid:
            #simply serve the site because if has the URID
            self.final_destination()
        else:
            #no urid, so we need to go the fw.asta.com to check if the urid is there
            self.redirect('http://fw.asta.com/?url=' + str(self.path))
```

As you can see the logic makes sense, however when I run the code, I run into an infinite redirect loop to the originally intended site.

When I get the redirect response, I can clearly see that the set-cookie field is there, however, when I get the redirected request, it does not send the cookie back to me.

Is this even the right way to go about the problem?  Any advice would be appreciated.